# How to get the size of downloading or uploading files from any appliction in android?

Tags: android

I`trying to make an android program which checks the internet traffic via 3G.The program should stop the download or upload if the size of currently downloading or uploading file is higher than a certain value.Does anyone know if it is possible to get the size of the files which are currently being downloaded or uploaded from any application?What i mean is that how can we track the data being downloaded or uploaded by any application.Does the android OS allow us to access these data?Thanks.

Comment: magic orb should help ... seriously ... too broad ... you can try to build proxy ... but it will be hard (based on your question)

Comment: Dear Selvin,do you know any resources from which i can learn how to create a proxy on client side in android?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For downloading, you can use this code, for getting size:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

For uploading file, before use:

```
File.length()
```

Comment: The blind leading the blind. He is not wana do this .... *which are currently being downloaded or uploaded from **any** application*

Comment: Thanks Okadzaki Tomoe, but what i mean is that how can we track the data being downloaded or uploaded by any application.Does the android OS allow us to access these data?